# How do I figure out if the minyan near my vacation rental is within techum shabbos?

Tags: shabbat

I will be staying this shabbos in Killington, VT. The closest Minyan I know of is a mile away, on google maps the whole way there looks pretty littered with homes, inns, and stores. How can I know for sure that it is within the techum?

Comment: Probably the rabbi there knows the relevant boundaries.

Comment: Do you seek the boundaries of the techum of killington vt, or in general how to calculate the techum of an arbitrary location?

Comment: Please rewrite your question to be more general. For the specific place you need to ask the local Rav. Note that a radius around the shul may not define the tchum.

Comment: Binyamin, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please note that "Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but *[does not offer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) personalized, professional advice*, and does not take the place of seeking such advice [from your rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)." To determine what to do this shabbos, I recommend that you consult your rabbi or, as @DoubleAA and sabbahillel have suggested, a rabbi in the locale you're visiting.